# Change embedded browser in Powerpoint

Tags: browser, microsoft-powerpoint

[image: Image of the error I see]

I have a plugin which invokes a web page. This site uses a JS which has a function (includes() method), which apparently isn't supported in Internet Explorer (the browser). The exact error is in the image, and the message is:
"The object doesn't accept the property or method 'includes"

If I try opening the URL directly in Internet, the site doesn't load. If I try opening it on Chrome or Firefox, it opens. [This is the URL](https://www.digitalexperience.ibm.com/content-picker/picker.html?apiUrl=https:%2F%2Fmy14.digitalexperience.ibm.com%2Fapi%2F6e223ecb-746e-4fe8-88e9-37ff2d12a185&fq=classification:asset&fq=assetType:image) that doesn't work on Internet, but does work in Chrome and Firefox.

I have no access to the code of this page. So basically, modifying it is not an option. Is there a way of changing the default browser that Powerpoint uses to display a plugin? This is a Windows computer.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to improve the terminology. "isn't supported in Internet" is pretty unclear.

Comment: @harrymc I tried to improve my terminology. Hope it's more clear now. Thanks!

Comment: "isn't supported in Internet" is still there. Do you mean "JavaScript"? Or maybe "browser"?

Comment: @harrymc explained it better... meant "isn't supported in Internet Explorer"

Answer (score 1):

See this - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_other-mso_2010/how-to-change-the-default-internet-browser-used-by/5994d1ae-b57d-4f56-bbca-a6d3259be33c?messageId=39f42769-948a-4855-95c4-aa7f6392e8d8&page=1

In the run program box, to open installed Chrome when my defect browser is Internet Explorer, I pasted:

> "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"http://www.bbc.co.uk

Obviously you need to change the

> www.bbc.co.uk

text to whatever hyperlink you require
Advantage is that it runs the browser from PowerPoint just for the required hyperlink rather than having to mess about with changing default browsers back and forth.
But beware though: requires you to enable macros to run...